# MySQL, multiple BIT operations in one column

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, bit

I have column named `settings` (type: tinyint unsigned not null).

That contains user settings in bits (0/1).

For example when i want update setting_1 then i do:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `settings`=`settings`|1
```

(That sets setting1 to 1 (true) ).

But, how i can do multiple update one column?
For example:

```
UPDATE `users`
SET
 `settings`=`settings`|1,
 `settings`=`settings`&~2,
 `settings`=`settings`|4
WHERE `user`='xyz';
```

Any links that explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform all the operations together, e.g.

```
update user 
set settings = settings|1&~2|4;
```

You can also use brackets to limit the scope. Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a4aef/1/0) for same.